# Create selection in tiny mce

Tags: tinymce, range

I'm using tiny mce in my application and applying properties to text using my customized tool bar. I works great on FF and Chrome as well, but on IE, it fails. It is caused by the click event of the color box. I have used mColorPicker plugin to apply color properties, but as I click on the color box in IE8, the selected text is deselected and as selection is null further code fails. The same flow works for select boxes where I set font and font sizes and the text remain selected though I click on the select boxes.

I was thinking that, I can remember the selection and select the same as focus is moved to the color box. I tried to understand the tinymce.dom.Selection documentation, but it could not help. Kindly guide me as I have spent lot of time in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the plugin responable for the color box or write an own plugin in order to save the selected element and apply color to it later.